# What is a good way to include position information of a word in feature vector?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, feature-extraction

I think bag of words is too simple for my task. I want some to include positional information of a word in feature vector. For example "good" is the second from the end, etc.

Comment: What stops you from trying this idea?

Comment: I mean, should I build a vector for each position? That seems a little to sparse.

Comment: Does it really matter if a term is second from the end or fourth from the end? If the answer is no, I'd recommend using n-grams instead of unigrams to capture a little more context (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram)

Comment: What is your aim to do that? If you want to use possibilities of which word comes from someone or something like that try to look at HMM based models.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases we use bigrams or trigrams of words as features: it carries most of the word order information in the sentence, while being much less sparse than positional information for each word.

For instance for the sentence `the cat ate the mouse` the trigrams features would be:

`<b> <b> the, <b> the cat, the cat ate, cat ate the, ate the mouse, etc.`

And you can leave your existing BOW features as well.

Moreover, if you use a discriminative model, you can add any feature that seems to be relevant to your task, even if this feature is not independent from your existing features.

Obviously the goal is always to find the right balance between information and sparsity... it depends on your dataset, you have to experiment !